# Xcode: shortcut for "Add Documentation" (⌥ + ⌘ + /) doesn't work

Tags: xcode, shortcut

I would like to quickly add a documentation block on top of my functions, using the expected shortcut (`⌥` + `⌘` + `/`).

If I add it from `Editor` > `Structure` > `Add Documentation` it works fine. However, as I am using a french AZERTY keyboard, typing `/` requires to handle ⇧ too.

So here is what happens:

- If I press `⌥`, `⌘` and `/`, nothing happens.
- If I press `⌥`, `⌘`, `/` and ⇧, Xcode adds a breakpoint on the line instead of generating a comment block (so I guess it recognizes another shortcut).

What should I do to fix this?

Thank you for your help